# how to restore angular 6 application interface status after closing the browser

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

We are currently a team developing a single page application with angular 6.

this application has one page "home" that contains a navigation bar and from that we can access to the application functionality.

each functionality represented in a window "[primeng dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog)" created dynamically in the home page.

so what we want to do is when a user reconnect after logout or closing the browser he can restore the home page in the last status when he was connected "windows opened before will reopen automaticly".

Our purpose is to create an application that can save her status like many other applications that save your workstation.

Comment: You'd have to store the values you need to re-open those components in local storage on the browser, or as part of the data returned when the user logs in so they can be restored.

Comment: note that status in North and attribute, I mean I must save all the interface window positions, windows content, data.... as possible as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment said, you will probably want to save that status in local storage. Anyone that has access to the computer has access to the local storage, so it is best to not put sensitive information in there. We typically try to only use database row id's and enums in local storrage.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.userStatus = localStorage.getItem('currentStatus');
}

someFunctionThatIsUsedToChangeStatus() {
    // logic to change status
    // ...

    localStorage.setItem('currentStatus', this.userStatus);
}
```

Comment: Another thing to note with local storage is that if the browser is in private mode, it won't be available. The safer option is to keep these settings on the database side and make them available on login.

Comment: note that status in North and attribute, I mean I must save all the interface window positions, windows content, data.... as possible as I can.

Comment: then it would be best to save that on the database. Then it will be secured and it will transfer over to any device the user uses. So what they see on their work computer is what they will see on their home computer is what they see at the library's computer. Also, what you see in chrome is what you see in firefox is what you see in edge. Putting it in local storage will have different settings depending on which browser you switch to and which device you are working on

Comment: yes you're right. but the question is what are things that i must save. is there is any plugin that can help me doing this, "saving my work station". do you understand me ?

Comment: I understand what you are asking for, and right now I guess I don't have an answer. If you have a simple ui, then I would create a user_preference table in your database and just store the states of everything in there with a reference to the page_id and user_id. If it is a complex UI, then I don't know what the best option for you would be.